# Aligning an Expression - ! Missing } inserted

Tags: errors, align

I am getting this error when I run this code. It all looks exactly like a different instance in which I was aligning stuff and had no problem:

```
\begin{align}
B \times B &=
\lbrace (1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7), \right.    \nonumber\\
& \hspace{5mm} \left. (5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(5,7),(7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7) \rbrace      
\end{align}
```

The error is

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.275 \end{align}
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

I've just started with Latex so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: `\left` and `\right` should be a pair:
`\left\lbrace (1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7), \right. \nonumber \\\`
`& \hspace{5mm} \left. (5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(5,7),(7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7) \right\rbrace`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove \right. and \left. and you will get I believe you want.   \lbrace and \rbrace are not required to be paired.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
B \times B &=
\lbrace (1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7),    \nonumber\\
& \hspace{5mm} (5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(5,7),(7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7) \rbrace      
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To split something like that, we have `multline`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
B \times B =
\{ (1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7),    \\
 (5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(5,7),(7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7) \}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Several good answers have already been given, but I would do things a little bit differently.

Like R. Schumacher, I would not use a `\left`, `\right` pair. Only I would put a `\bigl`, `\bigr` pair instead. (Two `\big` instructions would also have served, but `\bigl` and `\bigr` are more coherent and readable in this case, since they are supposed to be placed before left and right delimiters.)

Since there is only one equation, I would use an `equation` environment instead of `align`.

And as Harish Kumar suggested, I would split this equation in two lines, but since it is inside one equation here, the `multlined` environment of the `mathtools` package (a superset of `amsmath`) would be of use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}
       B \times B = \bigl\lbrace (1,1),(1,3),(1,5),(1,7),(3,1),(3,3),(3,5),(3,7), \\
       (5,1),(5,3),(5,5),(5,7),(7,1),(7,3),(7,5),(7,7) \bigr\rbrace
     \end{multlined}     
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]